# Why string search is case-sensitive in sybase whereas its not in many other databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sybase, rdbms

I have used `SQL Server` & `MySQL` RDMS databases in my app development. I am new to `sybase` database in which I found that the string search is by default case-sensitive whereas in `SQL Server` and `MySQL` its not. 
1. Is there any SQL Standard regarding string search case-sensitivity?
2. If there is unique key index over this string column, then will there be any issue if two rows found to be have same string but one in upper case and other in lower case?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 'Sample'
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 'sample'
```

Comment: In most RDBMS's, it's configurable whether each database/column is case-sensitive or not. The *default* for that setting varies between products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think it depends on `CHARACTER SET` and `collation` in MySQL. Default character set is `latin1_swedish_ci` in which `ci` stands for case insensitive. You can change it to `latin1_swedish_cs` to make it case sensitive.

   In both MySQL and SQL server you can set character set and collation on column, table, database and server level.

   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html
2. Unique index will remove duplicates based on character set and collation. So if you have a `latin1_swedish_cs` then you will have two rows for 'Sample' & 'sample' and for `latin1_swedish_ci` you will have only first row 'Sample'. So all the string comparisons (in `WHERE, DISTINCT, GROUP BY`) inside database will based on the character set and collation which you have set.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain me about the question2? Also I am looking for configuring case-sensitivity in sybase

Comment: Thanks. So if we change character set, then SQL will try to rebuild index. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes if you change character set of existing table then it has update all the existing string values to new char set and also rebuild index.

Answer (score 1):

For Sybase ASE, the you will likely want to switch to the **nocase** sort order.

```
   sp_helpsort
```

- displays information about your current character set and sort order

  `select id, csid, name, descpription from master..syscharsets where type >= 2000`
- This will display a list of available sort orders

  `sp_configure 'default sort order', *sortorder_id*`
- Is the command to change the sort order.  For the ISO_1(ISO-8859-1) character set, the value would be '52'.  This setting is static, so the database must be restarted for it to take effect.

After restarting, run **sp_indsuspect** to check indexes, and **sp_tab_suspectptn** to check partitioned tables.  After this is done, you can check your changes by running **sp_helpsort** again.

It's important to be sure you have both database dumps, and BCP copies of your data when playing around with character sets/sort orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select in sqlserver with case sensitive search.. Try this

```
SELECT User_Id FROM Table 
WHERE User_Id=@userid AND Password=@pwd COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Here @userid & @pwd are the arguments sent from user into a stored procedure.